# How do you wall-hop in Roblox while in first person?

Tags: roblox

I know you can wall hop in Roblox using shift lock, but I still can't do it. I thought first person would be easier, but most videos don't use first person. **How do you wall-hop in first person?**

Comment: Which device do you play Roblox on? This video came out after the question was asked that shows someone wallhopping first-person on mobile. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wUK7n_9xrm8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Roblox wikia](https://roblox.fandom.com/wiki/Glitch#Wall_Hopping):

> When you **move your screen left to right very quickly with either first person or shift lock at the seam between two parts**, you can jump again. This is mainly used to climb ladders and trusses faster, though it can also be used on walls, where it is called Wall Hopping.